# How to crop out a SKLabelNode from a SKShapeNode?

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, skcropnode

[image]

I want to get the effect show above using the steps below.

---

Basically, it consists of a background image SKSpriteNode of

[image]

And I add a red color SKShapeNode on top of it

[image]

The I want to cut out the SKLabel Node off of that Red ShapeNode.

[image]

I have a code that could fake this effect. But, if you move the shape node, then the gimmick will be exposed.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        let baseNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "step1")
        baseNode.zPosition = 0
        baseNode.position = CGPoint(x:0,y:100)

        let shapeNode = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x:-155, y:-15), size: baseNode.size))
        shapeNode.fillColor = .red
        shapeNode.zPosition = 1
        addChild(shapeNode)

        let labelNode = SKLabelNode(text: "Hi")
        labelNode.fontColor = .white
        labelNode.fontName = "Arial"
        labelNode.fontSize = 185
        labelNode.zPosition = 2

        let cropNode = SKCropNode()
        cropNode.addChild(baseNode)
        cropNode.maskNode = labelNode
        cropNode.zPosition = 1
        addChild(cropNode)
    }
}
```

And If I try blend modes, it doesn't take me anywhere.]

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        let baseNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "step1")
        baseNode.zPosition = 0
        baseNode.position = CGPoint(x:0,y:100)
        addChild(baseNode)

        let shapeNode = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x:-155, y:-15), size: baseNode.size))
        shapeNode.fillColor = .green
        shapeNode.zPosition = 1
        addChild(shapeNode)

        let labelNode = SKLabelNode(text: "Hi")
        labelNode.fontColor = .red
        labelNode.fontName = "Arial"
        labelNode.fontSize = 185
        labelNode.zPosition = 2
        labelNode.blendMode = .subtract
        shapeNode.addChild(labelNode)

        let circle = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 40)
        circle.position = CGPoint(x:0,y:40)
        circle.fillColor = .green
        circle.blendMode = .subtract
        circle.zPosition = 3
        shapeNode.addChild(circle)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is not a tutorial site,  if you show some code, and some research, people will be more than happy to help you

Comment: See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/35991707

Comment: @Whirlwind nope. What I wanted is an inverse mask effect. The example you showed is just a usual mask effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you invert your thinking, this will be much easier.

Put the Red layer at the back/bottom. Lowest zPosition. Let's say `-1.0` for this example.

Put the picture on top of this, at a zPosition of `0.0`

Put the letter above, at a zPostion of `1.0`

So, from the screen of the iPhone, it's like this:

- Screen
- Letter
- Picture
- Red BG

You want to use the letter to mask out the picture.

Having done that, whenever you move the letter, it reveals the contents beneath itself, from the picture. Everything else is RED.